# Fackbook app handle de-auth

Tags: php, facebook

i have a facebook app, which current turn on sandbox mode
my app will auto kick ppl out to install the app when they dont have the app or they havent login

my app also have a btn to vote something, it will be a ajax function, the ajax will return message when people havnt install the app/havent login, and then call fb.login() to ask people to login in a popup

i was testing a case, assume i installed the app,

1. i go to the page which has ajax button
2. Then i open my account page on another browser tab, and then delete the app
3. i swap the browser tab to the page
4. i click the btn, the ajax return not installed message and it call fb.login()
5. it will pop up a error popup, which i check the popup url, it's segment contains a accessToken
6. and then i click the btn again , the ajax return not installed message and it call fb.login()
7. it pop up the login box normally

the difference is the success login url will not contains accessToken in the url segment

Can anyone tell me how to handle this case, if i reli want people login in a popup box once they delete the app and havent refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

Generally, before you do anything in Javascript, you can check they are still logged in by calling Facebook servers `[getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)'.  Then handle your actions once that call responds.

You can also use the [event subscribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) listener that sits in your HTML page. If the user logs out then you can force a refresh

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
});
```

If you call back to PHP then each PHP page should initiate the facebook object (check the [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)) and check the user is logged in.

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Comment: Thx for the comment, but my case is un-install application instead of logout